# Isolating unique observations and calculating the average in Stata

Tags: unique, average, stata

Currently I have a dataset that appears as follows:

```
 mnbr      firm       contribution
 1591      2          1
 9246      6          1
 812       6          1
 674       6          1
```

And so on.  The idea is that mnbr is the member number of employees who work at firm # whatever.  If contribution is 1 (and I have dropped all the 0s for this purpose) said employee has contributed to a certain fund.
I additionally used codebook to determine the number of unique firms that exist.  The goal is to determine the average number of contributions per firm i.e. there was 1 contribution for firm 2, 3 contributions for firm 6 and so on. The problem I arrive at is accessing that the unique values number from codebook.
I read some documentation online for

```
inspect *varlist*
display r(N_unique)
```

which suggests to me that using r(N_unique) would store that value, yet unfortunately this method did not work for me.  So that is part 1.

Part 2 is I'd also like to create a variable that shows the contributions in each firm i.e.

```
 mnbr      firm       contribution      average
 1591      2          1                 1
 9246      6          .                 2/3
 812       6          1                 2/3
 674       6          1                 2/3
```

to show that for firm 6, 2 out of the 3 employees contributed to this fund.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: See http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/calculating-number-of-distinct-values/ and references within.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer I already tried that documentation.  Upon implementing the code I received the error "r(101) factor variables and time-series operators not allowed."  Any ideas?

Comment: "Did not work for me" is not a good way to report problems. People are left guessing what went wrong. It's also good idea to post **exact** code and errors, if any. The stored result `r(N_unique)` will be that of the last variable in the variable list. Try `inspect firm` (only one variable; the one you are interested, I believe).

Comment: @RobertoFerrer When I implement `inspect firm` I get the desired output that produces a histogram and a table with the number of positive, zero, and negative entries among others.  However when I try to implement `display r(N_unique)` the output is only `.` and stata does not appear to be working on it any further.  Hope that makes sense, it just outputs nothing for me, which is why I said it did not work for me, though I certainly should have clarified).

Comment: See http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0042 for a review of calculating the number of distinct observations, including why "unique" is poor terminology for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your comment, this works for me:

```
clear
set more off 

input ///
 mnbr      firm       cont
 1591      2          1
 9246      6          .
 812       6          1
 674       6          1
 end

list

// problem 1
inspect firm
display r(N_unique)

// problem 2
bysort firm: egen totc = total(cont)
by firm: gen share = totc / _N

list
```

You have to use `r(N_unique)` before running another Stata command, or it can get lost. You can also save that result to a `local` or `scalar`.

Problem 2 is also addressed.